# Find the radical of an ideal in the ring of polynomials over the complex numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, commutative-algebra, noetherian

In $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,W]$ I have the following ideal
$$I=(XZ-Y^2,XW-YZ,X^2-WY,YX-WZ,YW-Z^2,ZX-W^2).$$
I'm trying to find it's radical using Hilbert Nullstellensatz, i.e., trying to find the set of elements that vanishes at all the points of the variety of $I$. The bad news is that the variety of $I$ is not the easiest set to find. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, it will be made of only elements of $\mathbb{C}$.

I found that the following sets are in the variety of $I$:

- $(a,a,a,a)\in\mathbb{C}^4$, $\forall a\in\mathbb{C}$
- $(-a,-a,-a,a)\in\mathbb{C}^4$, $\forall a\in\mathbb{C}$
- And the same as the above but with $a$ in different positions.

I managed to find these by seeing that $X^2-Z^2=(X-Z)(X+Z)$ and $Y^2-W^2=(Y-W)(Y+W)$ are in $I$ and trying to find a set of elements that vanishes these, but I have no idea how to find every single element. Besides, I don't know if this is the best approach, I could try to find the intersection of all ideals too.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method. Note that, although your ideal turns out to already be radical, this method does *not* prove that.

The [rational normal curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_normal_curve) of degree 3 is
$$C := \{[s^3:s^2t:st^2:t^3]\in\Bbb P^3 \mid [s:t]\in \Bbb P^1\}.$$

**Step 1:** Prove that $C = V(Z^2-YW, YZ-XW, Y^2-XZ)$ (inside $\Bbb P^3$).

**Step 2:** Prove that $V(I)\subseteq C$ (here, I'm using $V(I)$ to mean the vanishing locus in projective space).

**Step 3:** Use the definition of $C$ to find $V(I)$ explicitly. You'll end up with a finite set of points.

**Step 4:** Use the projective Hilbert Nullstellensatz to express $\sqrt{I}$ as an intersection of prime ideals.